# 110v outlet convert to disconnect?

Tags: circuit-breaker, air-conditioning, mini-split

I have a 110v outlet with a dedicated 20 amp breaker. My question is can I remove outlet and run the same 12/2 wire to the outside wall about 4 feet away from outlet and turn it into a disconnect box for a mini split 115v? [image: outlet]

Comment: What room/space does this outlet serve? Are there other outlets within 6' of it along the wall?

Comment: This outlet is in my bedroom it is a dedicated circuit 20amp breaker for my portable AC but the portable ac is not cooling my room enough so i bought a 115v mini split. There is an outlet about 2 feet away from it on the right side to the left there is none. The wall on the left is where i would run the wire to outside to the disconnect box.

Comment: Also the panel is directly behind the outlet on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a blank junction box cover on the box and connect with WET RATED WIRE to your OUTDOOR disconnect box 4 feet away.

I'd use conduit and THWN, you might choose 12/2 UF cable. Running interior dry type cable to exterior boxes is a code violation; a common one, but a violation never the less.

Answer (score 0):

You can move that to the outside to feed a mini split/ disconnect . Don’t forget you also need a standard 120v receptacle “within sight” . However if the panel is right there I would pull a new circuit so you don’t have a hole to fix in your bedroom. 
It sounds like this dedicated receptacle was added based on your spacing so yes it could be moved.